# Webpack build generates code with empty files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was creating my dev environment following the webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/). I set up my local one and  I realized when the build is run, the result has some code and the entry file is empty. Is there a way to prevent webpack adds that code?

My **webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: '.src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

The index file is completely empty

Comment: Whats the difference between the entry file, index file and the result?

Comment: I think i understand you `__webpack_require__` is bundled by default, you can't get rid of it, otherwise your imports and exports won't work.

Comment: @Pavlo the inde file is empty. The result has: `!function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return ` ... more code

Comment: @Pavlo So I have to keep that piece of code ?

Comment: This is production mode code you are looking at try to run `webpack --mode=development` to see what it actually does

Comment: @Pavlo it created the same piece of code but without minifying it

Comment: `(function(modules) { var installedModules = {}; function _webpack_require__(moduleId) { if(installedModules[moduleId]) { return installedModules[moduleId].exports; }` This is what mine creates, they look very similar

Comment: I need to avoid this

Comment: Avoid what? the minified code, or the __require__ without it webpack won't work. I wonder why your development mode creates a production mode bundle, are you sure you spelled it correctly?

Comment: @Pavlo Yep, I am pretty sure. If webpack needs it I think I should change my bundler then.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid some kind of import, export function regardless of what you use. Non minified its only 85 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid the boilerplate code that webpack inserts into your final file. All that code is used by webpack to manage the imports of different modules on your application.